# What has happened to this site?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, chat

The currently weekly rep stats are the same as the quarterly rep stats for users, indicating there has not been a lot of dynamics over the past quarter. The chat room is empty, it used to be lively and full of participants.

I originally joined this site when it was launched and I'm shocked to see how quiet it is. I'm wondering if it is on track to graduate from beta and if anyone knows why it has gotten so quiet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the quarter just started with October, so don't read too much into that set of stats! However, yes, there's definitely a slow down from the initial days of the site and we could remain in indefinite beta should that continue (they no longer shut it down after a time window).

In the end, only a few of us serious regulars have kind of stuck around and we're not really loaded up with questions, we're kind of hanging to answer. I'm seeing that with a few sites these days... It's kind of tied to how many tech folks have a strong enough interest in it because the vast majority of the traffic comes from that segment of the population. So, for example, the Photography site does steady business, but the Pets or Arts & Crafts sites do not.

By the way, welcome back. :)

Comment: Ah the quarter starting with October.. yes.. Thank God for that. And thanks for the welcome, I don't have time to be so active, but have horses again and thought I can visit and will post some Qs for horses :)

Comment: I hypothesize that it also has to do with availability and popularity of good forums for the same topic elsewhere. Similar to the reasons why e.g. CAD proposals have failed on Area 51 at *least* three times, despite massive activity on e.g. AutoCAD forums and continued heavy use and popularity of the software. The way to poke through in these cases is to have significant higher quality than existing resources, which is a really tough balance: You don't want to be too picky initially because you want all the questions/answers you can get, but if you're *too* lax you don't rise above.